# How to swap the buffers in 2 windows emacs

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs I find that sometimes I have 2 files separated into 2 windows.

For example:
I open 1 file using <kbd>C-x C-f file1.c RET</kbd>

and I split the frame into two windows: <kbd>C-x 3</kbd>

I then open another file <kbd>C-x C-f file2.c RET</kbd>

So I have 2 files:

window 1 (left) `file1.c`

window 2 (right) `file2.c`

I am wondering if there is any key combination to swap the files over? Normally I like to work on the left window when I have 2 window. I know I can easily do <kbd>C-x o</kbd>to move the cursor to the right window.

However, I am just wondering if I can swap the files so that `file2.c` is in the left window and `file1.c` is in the right window?

Comment: This also works (tested in emacs24): [Transposing Two Buffers](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers#toc7) It seems similar to *Bahbar* answer

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I use [buffer-move](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/buffer-move.el) for this. Now if you are working on the buffer on the left side, calling 'buf-move-right' will swap it with the one on the right. I guess this is what you want.

Comment: This solution is perfect, and the comments are very clear - just make sure you read them :)

Comment: If you just want to swap windows (independent on the selected one), you can use the following `(defun win-swap ()
  "Swap windows using buffer-move.el"
  (interactive)
    (if (null (windmove-find-other-window 'right))
        (buf-move-left)
      (buf-move-right)))`

Comment: buffer-move didn't work for me with the layout of just two windows but with `win-swap` it worked just fine, thanks!

Comment: Inside that buffer-move source you'll see a comment about the all-important mappings for `C-S-up` to `buf-move-up` etc.

Answer (score 70):

In the Emacs 26.1 NEWS file there is the following entry:

```
+++
*** New command 'window-swap-states' swaps the states of two live
windows.
```

Which appears to offer similar functionality to [`crux-transpose-windows`](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux/blob/4f5c8fefd5a6aa52e128c4a0401cc86410d6ac8f/crux.el#L437-L451) but can also do some height/width transpositions?

Comment: easy and effective

Comment: Easy, effective, and **built-in**, no third party needed. This did exactly what I wanted when I had 4 files open, it swapped the left one with the right one and left the other two alone. Emacs 27.2.

Comment: So easy, but why is this so slow? Takes about 2 secs to execute

Answer (score 36):

The [transpose-frame](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeFrame) library provides a pretty comprehensive set of functions for flipping or rotating the window arrangements in frames.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `flop-frame` <kbd>RET</kbd> does what this particular question needs.

The following diagrams are from the commentary in the library (and its EmacsWiki page):

```
‘transpose-frame’ … Swap x-direction and y-direction

       +------------+------------+      +----------------+--------+
       |            |     B      |      |        A       |        |
       |     A      +------------+      |                |        |
       |            |     C      |  =>  +--------+-------+   D    |
       +------------+------------+      |   B    |   C   |        |
       |            D            |      |        |       |        |
       +-------------------------+      +--------+-------+--------+

‘flip-frame’ … Flip vertically

       +------------+------------+      +------------+------------+
       |            |     B      |      |            D            |
       |     A      +------------+      +------------+------------+
       |            |     C      |  =>  |            |     C      |
       +------------+------------+      |     A      +------------+
       |            D            |      |            |     B      |
       +-------------------------+      +------------+------------+

‘flop-frame’ … Flop horizontally

       +------------+------------+      +------------+------------+
       |            |     B      |      |     B      |            |
       |     A      +------------+      +------------+     A      |
       |            |     C      |  =>  |     C      |            |
       +------------+------------+      +------------+------------+
       |            D            |      |            D            |
       +-------------------------+      +-------------------------+

‘rotate-frame’ … Rotate 180 degrees

       +------------+------------+      +-------------------------+
       |            |     B      |      |            D            |
       |     A      +------------+      +------------+------------+
       |            |     C      |  =>  |     C      |            |
       +------------+------------+      +------------+     A      |
       |            D            |      |     B      |            |
       +-------------------------+      +------------+------------+

‘rotate-frame-clockwise’ … Rotate 90 degrees clockwise

       +------------+------------+      +-------+-----------------+
       |            |     B      |      |       |        A        |
       |     A      +------------+      |       |                 |
       |            |     C      |  =>  |   D   +--------+--------+
       +------------+------------+      |       |   B    |   C    |
       |            D            |      |       |        |        |
       +-------------------------+      +-------+--------+--------+

‘rotate-frame-anti-clockwise’ … Rotate 90 degrees anti-clockwise

       +------------+------------+      +--------+--------+-------+
       |            |     B      |      |   B    |   C    |       |
       |     A      +------------+      |        |        |       |
       |            |     C      |  =>  +--------+--------+   D   |
       +------------+------------+      |        A        |       |
       |            D            |      |                 |       |
       +-------------------------+      +-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: `flop-frame` works only when the split between the windows is vertical, for horizontal split you need `flip-frame`.  However, `rotate-frame` works irrespectively; one command to swap the buffers between two windows, no matter what the split orientation :)

Answer (score 16):

If you are using [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) you can just use `C-c s` (`prelude-swap-windows`). From the Prelude documentation:

> `C-c s` runs the command `crux-swap-windows` (found in `prelude-mode-map`),
>   which is an alias for `crux-transpose-windows` in [crux.el](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux).

Comment: prelude looks like a mouthful (and it's not packaged anywhere - `curl | sh` = wtf?), but crux sure looks nice and does a bunch of stuff i rolled on my own in the first place.

Comment: i know what `curl | sh` is, what i am saying is: it's evil.

Answer (score 12):

As current emacs 29 version.
We have `windmove` , its like magic of swapping windows.

`windmove-swap-states-right`
`windmove-swap-states-up`
`windmove-swap-states-left`
`windmove-swap-states-down`

Answer (score 11):

I'm not aware of any built-in function doing this.

However, it does not seem too difficult to whip up some elisp for doing it. Devil is in the details though.

```
(defun swap-buffers-in-windows ()
  "Put the buffer from the selected window in next window, and vice versa"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((this (selected-window))
     (other (next-window))
     (this-buffer (window-buffer this))
     (other-buffer (window-buffer other)))
    (set-window-buffer other this-buffer)
    (set-window-buffer this other-buffer)
    )
  )
```

Notably, this may not be doing what you desire with respect to where the caret ends up.
However, you'd first have to say what you want :p

Comment: I copied and pasted this code, and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it does do something, it swaps the top and bottom parts of the Emacs window. I was expecting it to swap the frames.

Comment: ok. You're confusing me. you mentioned C-x 3. This is to create 2 emacs windows, not 2 emacs frames. Are you using frames or windows ? What do you call windows and what do you call frames?

Comment: also, you did not talk about top and bottom parts. Do you have more than 2 buffers showing at once ?

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question, I'm just an interloper. I had never used C-x 3 before I saw this question, but as you say it splits the Emacs window, rather than creating a new frame.

Comment: doh. Sorry. I should have noticed

Comment: Well, your answer seems to be correct! For some reason I am chronically incapable of understanding Lisp despite my efforts.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was wrong. I guess I should have been using Windows instead of frames.

Answer (score 2):

If you have prelude, you can use ace-window with `S-w`. From there you can do many things listed in their [docs](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window).

> You can also start by calling ace-window and then decide to switch the
>   action to delete or swap etc. By default the bindings are:
>
> x - delete window
>
> m - swap (move) window
>
> c - split window fairly, either vertically or horizontally
>
> v - split window vertically
>
> b - split window horizontally
>
> n - select the previous window
>
> ...

So it would be `S-w m`

Comment: For Spacemacs users, `ace-swap-window` is bound to `SPC w M`. This functionality is available by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Ace window](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window), which I highly recommend, you can swap buffers with `ace-swap-window`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet can do switch buffer.

```
(defun ab/switch-buffer-each-other (arg)
  "switch current buffer with other window buffer 
   right-2-left and up-2-down"
  (interactive "p")
  (cond
   ((windmove-find-other-window 'right) (buf-move-right))
   ((windmove-find-other-window 'left) (buf-move-left))
   ((windmove-find-other-window 'up) (buf-move-up))
   ((windmove-find-other-window 'down) (buf-move-down)))
(message "switch buffer done"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would contrive to open up file #2 in the desired location, i.e. after you hit c-x 3, move the cursor with c-x o before navigating to the second file.