# Move window in emacs

Tags: emacs

In i3 there's a neat way to move the current window around the desktop.

Say I have windows

> XXX|YYY

and I'm in window X. With Shift+Win+Down I can change the layout to

> YYY
>
> ---
>
> XXX

Pressing Shift-Win-Up gives

> XXX|YYY

again and pressing Shirt-Win-Up once again gives

> XXX
>
> ---
>
> YYY

I would like to have the same for emacs windows within one emacs frame, but so far I haven't figured out a way how to do it. I'm familiar with winmove-<up/down>, but this just changes the active window. buf-move keeps the layout but just switches buffers between windows. So far I haven't found a way to get a behavior similar to i3.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate question. I don't have time to look for that now, but maybe someone else can.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/1774832/324105 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8648522/324105 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/17415235/324105

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because *none* of these replies address the functionality I was asking about. I know that I can change the split (horizontal to vertical and vice versa) and I know how I can switch buffer inside existing windows.